Where is a safe place to add a metadata file to a server-side SVN repository folder?
I want to add a custom json file to the server-side folder structure of an SVN repository, such that it doesn't mess with SVN, and doesn't get messed with by SVN either. It should just exist peacefully, and SVN should be oblivious to the fact it's even there.
When I create a new repository, I get the following top-level-structure:
conf/
db/
hooks/
locks/
format
README.txt
svn.ico
The README.txt says

This is a Subversion repository; use the 'svnadmin' and 'svnlook'
tools to examine it.  Do not add, delete, or modify files here
unless you know how to avoid corrupting the repository.
Visit http://subversion.apache.org/ for more information.

First of all, I get that deleting, modifying or moving files would break things. But adding should be safe in general (unless I happen to match the path of an optional config file by chance). Yet I wonder - is there any known place where I can safely put the file? I tried skimming the website "for more information", which unsurprisingly is not of much help for this question.
Clarifications:

I'm not asking how to add a versioned client-side file (svn add + svn commit), but a server-side file.

"File <-> repository" is a 1:1 relation, that's why I'd like to put the file in the respective folder, and not some "common" folder elsewhere on the drive.

I can't use SVN properties.



Add it into the repo’s root directory (the one with the README.txt file) or into the conf directory. Just think up some “unique” name for this file.

That is where I'd put it - I'm just afraid of some housekeeping/maintenance routine flagging it as "random unidentified garbage" and deleting it.

I’m unaware of any such cleanup routines in SVN. If you place the file, it should remain there forever.
